# How to clean up File Explorer's sidebar?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sidebar

I have several items on the Windows 10 File Explorer sidebar I would like to get rid of:

[image]

**In the case `A`** this is an old network share that does not exist anymore. I tried to remove it by right-clicking on the entry and choosing "disconnect". This did nto work (no messages, the `S:` drive stayed. I then tried to remove it in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\yop> net use s: /delete
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to s:.

Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]: Y
s: was deleted successfully.

PS C:\Users\yop> net use s: /delete
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

Despite the message the `S:` drive is still there (I also tried to delete it via the URI, same result)

**In the case of `B`**, this is a folder I added a long time ago via some voodoo actions and I have no idea how to revert it (remove it)

Comment: Type NET USE   to see what drives have been mapped.  Try right clicking on the network drive and delete the drive.  Restart the computer.

Comment: @John: this is what I did and explained in the question (including rebooting)

Comment: You might find `B` (Synching) by clicking in the Explorer Address bar and typing `shell:NetHood`.

Comment: @KeithMiller isn't `shell:NetHood` for network shortcuts? `B` is not a network shortcut but an additional entry into the sidebar (at the same level as "This PC", "Quick Access", ...)

Comment: @WoJ: Yes, you're right. I'm visually imaiared and was zoomed in so far I couldn't compare indentation. So it's most likely an entry under `[HKCU|HKLM]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\Namespace`

Answer (score 0):

**Case B**: use the free (not open-source) [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaerotweaker.com/): `File Explorer`→ `Navigation Pane - Custom Items`

Other tweakers may work as well, I can confirm that this one works great for that (no affiliation, just a new happy user)

Comment: So it was a `...\Desktop\NameSpace` item....

Comment: @KeithMiller yes indeed. I just had a look at the path and there is a UUID pointer that was created by Winaero Tweaker (a new one I added though that software)

Answer (score 0):

**Case A**: somehow I needed to reboot twice after

```
PS C:\Users\yop> net use s: /delete
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to s:.

Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]: Y
s: was deleted successfully.
```

It may have been a glitch, though - I believe that one reboot should be enough.